# Gradle Issue: could not find net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports

Tags: java, gradle

i am trying to compile jasper using gradle. But its showed me error like

```
 >gradle  -q compileJasperJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Execution failed for task ':compileJasperJava'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':jasperreports'.
   > Could not find net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.5.1.
     Required by:
         :Jasper:unspecified
```

my build.gradle code is

```
 configurations {
    jasperreports {
        transitive = true
    }
}
dependencies {     
    jasperreports 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.5.1' 
}

apply plugin: 'java' 
task compileOne (type: JavaCompile) {
    source = sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    include 'main/java/hello/JasperDemo.java'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
    destinationDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
} 
compileOne.options.compilerArgs = ["-sourcepath", "$projectDir/src/main/java"]

task compileJasperJava(dependsOn: 'compileOne') << {
    def jasperSourceDir = file('src')
    def jasperTargetDir = file('build/classes/main/jasperreports')
    ant {
        taskdef(name: 'jrc', classname: 'net.sf.jasperreports.ant.JRAntCompileTask', classpath: configurations.jasperreports.asPath)
        jasperTargetDir.mkdirs()
        jrc(srcdir: jasperSourceDir, destdir: jasperTargetDir) {
            classpath(path: sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
            include(name: '**/*.jrxml')
        }
    }
}
classes.dependsOn compileJasperJava
```

I used [this maven jasper depencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/5.5.1)
why this error >how to solve this?

Comment: Looks as if you didn't declare a repository.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser how to declare a repository for this ?

Comment: See the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser  I tried , but still could not solve it. Still i am facing this error. Can you please answer here so that i can accept your answer

Comment: First you should explain what exactly you tried, and what exact problems you encountered.